# Authentication between web server and sql server

Tags: sql-server

So, we're restructuring out development environment.  We've installed SQL Server onto it's own server, and we are publishing our internal web applications onto a seperate web server.  However, the problem is that for some reason the authentication of the user between the web server and sql server gets lost, resulting in the Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' error.

Where do i start troubleshooting?  SQL Server is set up for TCP and remote connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'some reason' is called **constrained delegation**:

- [How To: Use Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx)
- [Configuring Constrained Delegation for IIS (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a71be370-c7db-4f98-bd03-c6e32c4d8075.mspx?mfr=true)
- [IIS 7.0: Configuring Servers for Delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296638%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Kerberos Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739587%28WS.10%29.aspx)